# Can't interact with textfields and movieclips

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a movieclip on stage: I load inside it a form (via addChild). The form is made of textfields and movieclips and it is contained in a library object of MyForm class, extending MovieClip. So I have:

```
var myForm:MyForm = new MyForm();
myClip.addChild(myForm);
```

What happens: the MyForm class lets me interact with textfields (if I change a value of a textfield I can see it very clearly). But **I can't manually reach the input textfields and the buttons (they don't respont to pressure, and I can't modify their content in the case of textfields)**. There seems to be something related to the fact that MyForm is contained inside myClip because if I load the form without the myClip container anything works again. I tried to use `mouseChildren` and `mouseEnabled` on myClip but it doesn't work. What can I do (aside from eliminate the container)?

Comment: Tell us more about myClip. How was it created? Does it have multiple frames?

Comment: Are you saying it works.. when you do: stage.addChild(myForm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any possibility of there being something positioned in front of your form elements?  To test this, you can add this code to and display object that is on the stage, or to your document root.  It should tell you which object is actually capturing your mouse interaction:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onMouseClickStage);

function onMouseClickStage(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("Mouse interacted with: "+evt.target);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it was this, I discovered it before reading your post but you're right: who gave me the FLA forgot to mention that there was a giant invisible movieclip loaded at runtime upon the movieclip I was working on...